# dynamic correlation between vectors (with sampling)

Tags: r, time, correlation

Say, I have two vectors of the same length

```
A = mtcars$mpg
B = mtcars$cyl
```

I can calculate correlation between whole vectors

```
cor (A, B)
```

and get one single value (`-0.852162`).

What I need is to calculate correlation between the two vectors with a sampling rate of 10, which means I start at the first datapoint in A and B, take 5 values on the right from it (there are no values on the left), calculate a correlation coefficient ad write it in a vector C. Then I take the next value in A & B, take 5 values on the right and 1 on the left, write it into a vector; then shift again to the next value and so forth. The resulting vector C must contain the same number of values as A or B (N=32), and each value in C represents a correlation b/w A and B with a sampling rate 10 (5 values on the left and 5 on the right from that datapoint, if availible).
Is there any elegant and simple way to do it in R?

P.S.: The ease of coding is more important, than the time needed for calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TTR` package may provide what you are looking for.

It should be as simple as:

```
TTR::runCor(A, B)
```

There is a whole blog post about rolling correlation [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/tidy-time-series-analysis-part-3-the-rolling-correlation/).

Comment: I have a problem with this formula: I get a message "Error in runCov(x, y, n, use = use, sample = sample, cumulative) : 
  Series contain non-leading NAs". Adding to the formula runCor(..., na.rm = TRUE) doesn't help, I get instead "Error in runCor(data$force_left[tr, ], data$force_right[tr, ], n = 50,  : 
  unused argument (na.rm = T)". Do you have an idea how to fix it?